# loop with several conditions

Tags: r, loops, nested

I need to do a loop with several conditions (create three diferent objects several times) and with a loop nested. 
I write this:

```
metaxcan <- c("foo1.csv", "foo2.csv")
predix_asso <- c("soo1.csv", "soo2.csv")



for (i in metaxcan){
 for (j in predix_asso){
  PGC<-read.csv(i, header=T, sep=",")
  asociacion<-read.table(j, header=T, sep="") 

PGC_predix <- merge(PGC,asociacion,by="gene")
   ngenes<-nrow(PGC_predix_1)    


print(ngenes)
  }
 }
```

But instead of print just 2 numbers (the merge between foo1 and soo1; and the merge of foo2 and soo2), it prints 4 numbers (all interactions)

How can I do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but won't it be enough to just use one loop?

```
metaxcan <- c("foo1.csv", "foo2.csv")
predix_asso <- c("soo1.csv", "soo2.csv")



for (i in metaxcan){

  PGC<-read.csv(i, header=T, sep=",")
  asociacion<-read.table(i, header=T, sep="") 

PGC_predix <- merge(PGC,asociacion,by="gene")
   ngenes<-nrow(PGC_predix_1)    


print(ngenes)
}
```

Comment: ok, it works... I didn't understand, the names of the first element in metaxcan and in predix_asso have different name, because of that I thought it will not work with just one loop

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confused as to how the for loop works. Running the code below you will be able to see how it exactly uses the inputs for i and j.

```
for(i in metaxcan)for(j in predix_asso)print(paste(i,j))
```

For you problem i suggest using a single for loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(metaxcan)){
    PGC <- read.csv(metaxcan[i], header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    asociacion<-read.table(predix_assp[i], header=T, sep = "") 
    PGC_predix <- merge(PGC, asociacion, by = "gene")
    print(ngenes <- nrow(PGC_predix))
}
```

Here i use `seq_along` which will make an integer vector along the length of metaxcan (similar to `1:length(metaxcan)`, but it handles the case when the length is 0 without error)

Comment: Perfect, it works, thank you very much. I didn't understand, the names of the first element in metaxcan and in predix_asso have different name, because of that I thought it will not work with just one loop